# C# Run through a textfile with placeholders and replace placeholders with user input

Tags: c#

So my text file will have something like this "Hi, my name is [0], and I study at [1]..." and so on, with the number increasing. At the placeholder, I want to replace the placeholder with user input.

I've looked at previous questions, but I can't find one that integrates user input effectively.

Code so far-

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
textBox1.Text = input;
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]", Console.ReadLine());
string result2 = result.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);
textBox2.Text = result2;
```

It crashes when I try to load my text file due to an error in the `Console.ReadLine()` part. I'm assuming I need a loop to iterate through the text in the text file to find each placeholder and ask for user input, but I'm not sure how to work that out.

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx string format?

Comment: Do you know in advance the content of you file or will it be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know how it goes

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
//Hi, my name is {0} and I study at {1}...
textBox1.Text = input;
//Get your name and school here
var name = "";
var school = ""
textBox2.Text = string.Format(input, name, school);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method should help you:

```
public static string AdjustString(string str, List<string> userInput)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var input in userInput)
    {
        var searchedSubstring = $"[{i}]";
        str = str.Replace(searchedSubstring, input);
        i++;
    }
    return str;
}

static void UsgeExample()
{
    var newString = AdjustString("[0][1][2]123[3]",
        new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"});
}
```

newString = "ABC123D"

Also, you can try a Dictionary with the key = "[0]" or "[1]", etc and values which you want to see instead of these keys.